# Why did Denji pass out, and why was he dizzy in Himeno's appartment?

Tags: chainsaw-man

In episode 7, everyone's out eating and drinking at the izakaya, and Denji explicitly mentions he's only drinking tea:

[image: Denji saying "just tea" in response to being asked if he's been drinking]

However, later in that episode, he is apparently passed out and Himeno takes him on her back back to her apartment. Later, he wakes up in her bed and says he's dizzy.

Do we know why he passed out, and why he was dizzy? Did he get intoxicated from the vomit he swallowed earlier from the kiss with Himeno, since she had been drinking heavily? Or was there some other reason for his passing out and dizziness?

Comment: Vomiting profusely takes a lot out of you and leaves you dehydrated too

Answer (score 1):

He was sick firstly from having vomited from Himeno vomiting in his mouth, and then secondly he may have been dizzy because he hadn't drunk alcohol before and she momma-birds it into his mouth when he says he is thirsty.

His passing out may have been from just exhaustion but who can say.

Comment: The question is more about why he passed out before getting to her place, though, so her "momma-birding" it wouldn't be relevant yet. In any case, even when he wakes up, he says he's dizzy almost immediately, and alcohol doesn't go to your head that quickly.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe Denji passes out before getting to her place. The timeline of events is that they're at the bar and they drink a lot (except Denji), Himeno kisses him, he vomits in the toilet, and then he carries her to her house since she had passed out. After reaching her house, he probably passed out as well due to sheer exhaustion and having vomited profusely before, and that is why he is dizzy and thirsty. Vomiting causes dehydration.

Translations of the manga in different languages show both Himeno carrying Denji and Denji carrying Himeno, but since the anime showed her carrying him, it is safe to assume that is the canon event. Even then, it makes sense for Denji to have passed out after being awake late and vomiting over and over.

Comment: I believe _she_ carried _him_ to her house, not the other way around.

Comment: @JNat I don't know when it happens in the anime, but in the manga, Vol.3 Ch.21 "The Taste of a Kiss" Page 15, you can see Makima ask where Denji is and Fushi says "I'm pretty sure I saw him head off with Himeno on his back?"

Comment: In the anime it definitely happens the other way around ([ref](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WO7v1.jpg)). Will try to find the exact text in Japanese to see if it might've been a translation error.

Comment: The exact text in Japanese appears to be "デンジ君なら姫野先輩が背負って連れて行きましたよ？" ([ref](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fcX5I.png)). I plopped that into Google Translate, and despite some confusion surrounding the right pronouns for each person, the grammatical structure hints at Himeno having carried Denji on her back, as the anime shows.

Comment: I am trying to find the original source in Japanese but if in the anime it shows Himeno carrying him, then it is most likely the right transaltion. I checked some translations in other languages and they also can't decide who was carrying who. Regardless, it still makes sense that Denji passed out and was dizzy from sheer exhaustion and dehydration. I will edit this into the answer